# MediaWiki PageForms: Combobox not showing as option in Special:CreateProperty

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, semantic-mediawiki

I set up Mediawiki with

```
Page Forms  5.2.1
Semantic MediaWiki  2.5.8
```

However, when I try to create a combobox property at *Special:CreateProperty* I cannot find Combobox in the drop down menu. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combobox is not a property type (data type), it's an input type of a form field.
The correct workflow is the following :

- Create properties with a specific [data type](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:List_of_datatypes)
- [Create a template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Page_Forms_and_templates) which defines fields and associate them with properties
- Create a form from the template which defines how fields are set ([input type](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Page_Forms/Input_types)), such as combobox.

Comment: HI! I created a text input type, a template and then when creating a form I cannot select Combobox as an option in the Input type Dropdown menu (?) - only textarea (default)  and (Hidden)

Comment: You can change from text to keyword type if you are only storing short text, or you can edit the form manually to force combobox input type